# Measure of the union of a family of sets of $2^\omega$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, solution-verification

Consider $2^\omega$ with the usual measure, consider a countable family of strings of the same lenght $(s_i)_{i<\omega}$ such that the sets of coordinates they specify is pairwise disjoint, for example each $s_i$ specifies coordinates from $in+1$ to $(i+1)n$.

I am trying to prove that the set of points $x$ of $2^\omega$ such that $x\in[s_i]$ for some $i$ has measure $1$. When the strings are of length $1$ then it is clear because looking at the complementary is obvious that it has measure $0$, and taking the union of such kind of conditions we have a family of events which is strictly increasing in probaility, but I can't show that it goes to $1$. Is it even true?

I think in the easier case where each $s_i$ specifies coordinates from $in+1$ to $(i+1)n$ there is an easy proof. This is because the measure of the set $ \{x : x\notin [s_i] \text{ for } i=1,\dots,m\}$ is $(\frac{2^{n-1}-1}{2^{n-1}})^{m-1}$ and this converges to $0$ as $m$ goes to $\infty.$ But what if the $s_i$ do not cover all the possible coordinates?

Let me try to generalize the previous argument by adding some 'padding', divide the space in such a way that $s_i$ says something about $n$ coordinates of a set of $n+m_i$ coordinates still disjoint pairwise ( here $m_i$ is the 'padding' ), with this trick we can now assume that we cover every single coordinate. Now the measure of $x\notin [s_i]$ is $\frac{(2^{n}-1)2^{m_i}}{2^{n+m_i}}=\frac{2^{n}-1}{2^{n}}$ and the measure of $ \{x : x\notin [s_i] \text{ for } i=1,\dots,m\}$ is $(\frac{2^{n}-1}{2^{n}})^{m-1}$.

Comment: What if $s_i$ specifies the single number $2i$?

Comment: Sorry but $\omega$ is an ordinal or an integer, I suppose integer but this is confusing form me.

Comment: It still holds right? because in that case $x\notin[s_i]$ for every $i<\omega$ has measure $0$ since we are specifying infinitely many coordinates.

Comment: @JulesBesson $\omega$ is an ordinal here, I mean $2^\mathbb{N}$ if that is more clear.

Comment: Okok thanks!   :)